# HTML 5 report designer

Tags: javascript, html, reporting-services

Is it possible to create a HTML5 report designer which allow users to generate report templates from JSON data? We are using Xtra reports as of now but we are thinking of pushing the report generation logic to the client side for better performance.

There are many JavaScript libraries to convert html to PDF but is there a way to design HTML5 templating from the JSON structure?Since the design of report is customer specific we need the end users to edit the templates.So is it possible to make something like End user report designer in HTML5 and saving the templates?We want the user to edit the templates from websites rather than a windows form based application

Any examples or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Per the flagging menu: _"Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it"_...

Comment: I have removed the words tools and libraries.I want to know if someone has succeeded in creating HTML5 report designer.With HTML5 supporting pretty much anything these days I don't think this questions is off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stimulsoft](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/press-releases/stimulsoft-reports-2013-1-brings-html-5-and-winrt-report-designers) has a HTML5 report designer .I am not sure about the JSON support though. There is also Adobe Flex Designer, which allows you to design reports at the client side.

Comment: I am looking for a better answer but it seems since this question is closed no one can answer.Thankyou for answering